# how to push to github using gittyup?

Tags: github

I found GittyUp after hours of searching `git client for linux`, and I must say it's amazing, but but but suddenly we cant push to github.

getting the following error...

> Unable to push to 'origin' - ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.
> Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.

I've logged into GittyUp by using PAT from github, which I generated by referring to this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: This error occurs when using ssh to contact GitHub. Ssh does not use PATs; those are specific to the case when you're using https to contact GitHub. None of this is a Git issue as Git simply pushes all the responsibility onto the system-provided libcurl (when using https) or the ssh program (when using ssh).

Comment: ok. maybe gittyup has something to do with that error then.

Comment: It probably does. Unfortunately there's no tag for it (and I had never heard of it before). A quick scan of https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup/blob/master/src/git/Remote.cpp suggests that it implements its own ssh (and https) and can use ed25519 keys, so if you wish to use it with ssh, figure out how to make it use an ed25519 key.

Comment: Or, if you wish to make it use https, figure out how to make it do that. Since it's not actually *Git* (not the C code version that the [tag:git] tag is about), it will have its own quirks. How you make it behave in the desired manner, I have no idea.

Comment: you are right. They are kind of using their own stuff. It worked flawlessly with vscode and other git clients, so I decided to ditch GittyUp for good.